# Sort list of objects interms of object's name

Tags: java

I have a **Fruit** model class:

```
public class Fruit{
   private String name;
   private String color;

   public Fruit(String name, color){
     this.name = name;
     this.color = color;
   }
   public getName(){
      return name;
   }
   public getColor(){
      return color;
   }
}
```

Then, I created a list of `fruits`:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

fruits.add(new Fruit("Orange","orange"));
fruits.add(new Fruit("Strawberry","red"));
fruits.add(new Fruit("Apple","green"));
fruits.add(new Fruit("Banana","yellow"));
```

Now, I would like to sort the `fruits` elements in **alphabetical order** in terms of **fruit name** . How can I efficiently sort the fruits list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following

```
Collections.sort(fruits);

public class Fruit implements Comparable {

    public int compareTo(Object o) {            
        Fruit f = (Fruit) o;
        return this.getName().compareTo(f.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: He needs to implement Comparable too (or supply a custom Comparator).

Comment: I would like to compare in terms of fruit.name, that's sort the list in name's alphabetical order. how should it be compared?

Comment: You should use "... implements Comparable<Fruit>", otherwise, it is fine

Comment: Is it really necessary to write `Comparable<Fruit>`? I have worked without using the class name. But I have change the `compareTo()` method slightly. If after modification of that, it's still not working, then please add the `Comparable<Fruit>`. Thanks

Comment: Although implementing Compararable works fine, I'd prefer the alternative solution of defining a Comparator (explained in the next answer). The idea of the Comparable interface is to define some kind of "natural order", and alphabetical order is not really natural for Fruits. However, it's all a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Collections.sort()`, defining a `Comparator`. For example:

```
Collections.sort(
    fruits,
    new Comparator<Fruit>()
    {
        public int compare(Fruit f1, Fruit f2)
        {
            // Ignore case for alphabetic ordering.
            return f1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(f2.getName());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `comparable` interface on the fruit class, and use `Collections.sort(list)`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator. For documentation take a look at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
{
   public int compareTo(Fruit f) {
       if (this.Name == f.Name)
           return 0;
       else if (this.Name > f.Name)
           return 1;
       else
           return -1;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
Collections.sort(fruits);
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a great idea for fruits to have a forced natural ordering.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Comparator<Fruit> fruitComparator = new Comparator<Fruit>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Fruit f1, Fruit f2) {

            return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
        }
    };
```

and then:

```
Collections.sort(fruits, fruitComparator );
```